# Unbounded convex conjugate

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

This is my first time posting a thread. I apologize if I somehow do not comply with the rules (please remind me if it happens, so next time I can do it correctly:)

Today I was having an optimization class, and had a question which my professor left unexplained.

Suppose f is a convex function from R^n to R (including infinity), and its conjugate is lower unbounded, then f is always infinite. I cannot see why, and I search online and textbook, but to little avail.

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain that a bit. Thank you!

Comment: Let $ f $ be the indicator function of the set $ S=\{b\}$, where $ b $ is a nonzero vector.  Then $ f^*(z) = z^T b$ is unbounded below, but $ f(b) $ is finite. Is this a counter example to what you want to show?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am not sure, but it appears to me that the statement may not be true usually, but is true for convex function....

Comment: But in my example, $ f $ is convex.  It's the indicator function of a convex set. I'm using "indicator function" in the convex analysis sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is false. Let $ b\in \mathbb R^n $ be nonzero and let $f $ be the indicator function of the set $ S=\{b\}$.  Then $ f^*(z) = \langle z, b\rangle$.  So $ f^*$ is unbounded below, but $ f(b)$ is finite.

(I'm using the term "indicator function" in the convex analysis sense.)